# Find three integers x, y, z such that there is a prime number that divides x and y, y and z, but not x and z?

Tags: prime-numbers

Recall that 1 isn't prime or composite.

I cannot think of any combinations. I am trying to find a counterexample to show that this relation is not transitive.

Comment: Do you mean "that divides $xy$, $yz$ but not $xz$"? Otherwise I have a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: If the prime number is different then $x=2\cdot3$, $y=3\cdot5$, $z=5\cdot 7$. If the prime number must be the same, then it is impossible because for the hypothesis it follows that $x=p\cdot a$, $y=p\cdot b$, $z=p\cdot c$, thus they are all divisible by $p$

Comment: What is "and" in this case? $+$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't expect it to be the same prime in every case, then $x=2, y=6, z=3$ is a solution.

Comment: This is the proper solution. There is a prime number p that divides both 2 and 6; namely, p = 2. There is a prime number p that divides both 6 and 3; namely, p = 3. There is not a prime number p that divides both 2 and 3. Thanks! I apologize for the confusion in the question; it's a tough one to word!

Comment: @Arctix No worries. Given what I think you're trying to prove, the ideal statement might be: "Show that the relation R given by $xRy \iff \text{hcf}(x,y)>1$ is not transitive".